# How to segmentation an Image in Python and save the new pieces of image segmented

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I would like to segmentation the image like this examle:
[full image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YpiDQuwJ2l-R5UXolspfQXAmBLPjpW0Q/view?usp=sharing)

And save in new images like this:
[new image purple star](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcl55SN-gtB-NpoVaUrSusQmq8iMzXY6/view?usp=sharing), [new image green star](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XSmatiPs3-QPT0c9yEzrDL9jI4ePdoP_/view?usp=sharing),  [new image orange star](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r18yXpyO7J-fIvXw_vN3i_euW1lReoEa/view?usp=sharing) and [new image pink star](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r2MCohwiYpWFO1MRiVWypVDme-I0S2_o/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I init this code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kMlp5dYELCLDyDzadb7CP256XfPL2LZN?usp=sharing but I'm new at Python and I've no idea how can I segmentation an image and save this in mutiple images,